# Show AdMob's adaptive banner in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, admob

I am following [official doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/swiftui#banner). My app has a simple `TabView` with just a Text and a Banner view as follows

```
  var body: some View {
      VStack {
          Text("Foo")
          Spacer()
          BannerView()
      }
  }
```

The issue is the BannerView() fits all the remaining space and if I put the `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` modifier on `BannerView()` the ad is showing behind the `TabView`.

[image]

The `BannerView()` code is exactly the same as the doc says.

```
struct BannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

static let shared: BannerView = BannerView()

@State
private var viewWidth: CGFloat = .zero

private let bannerView = GADBannerView()
private let adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
    let bannerViewController = BannerViewController()
    bannerView.adUnitID = adUnitID
    bannerView.rootViewController = bannerViewController
    bannerViewController.view.addSubview(bannerView)
    bannerViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
    
    return bannerViewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    guard viewWidth != .zero else { return }
    
    // Request a banner ad with the updated viewWidth.
    bannerView.adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(viewWidth)
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}

func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator(self)
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate {
    let parent: BannerView
    
    init(_ parent: BannerView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }
    
    // MARK: - BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate methods
    
    func bannerViewController(_ bannerViewController: BannerViewController, didUpdate width: CGFloat) {
        // Pass the viewWidth from Coordinator to BannerView.
        parent.viewWidth = width
    }
}
}
```

And the `BannerViewController` as follows

```
// Delegate methods for receiving width update messages.
protocol BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate: AnyObject {
    func bannerViewController(_ bannerViewController: BannerViewController, didUpdate width: CGFloat)
}


class BannerViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: BannerViewControllerWidthDelegate?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    
        // Tell the delegate the initial ad width.
        delegate?.bannerViewController(self, didUpdate: view.frame.inset(by: view.safeAreaInsets).size.width)
    }    
}
```

Comment: Did you ever end up finding a solution to this? Running into the exact same problem myself and can't find any resources to get this resolved

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem when working with tab view. Solved this issue by using height attribute.
Along with official doc, try this:

```
struct BannerAddView: View {
    var width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    
    var size: CGSize {
        return GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(width).size
    }
    var body: some View {
        
        BannerView()
            .frame( height: size.height)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested with the exactly same code you posted, I need to add an addition:

```
BannerView()
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 60, alignment: .bottomTrailing)
```

Ideally the SDK should calculate the banner size, unfortunately it's not working.

Comment: But the point of the adaptative banner is to not set the banner height or maxHeight. Is up to the sdk to calculate banner size

Comment: You are right @JavierCancio

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too and solved by implementing the iOS 16+ method `sizeThatFits(_:uiViewController:context:)` on `BannerView` and returning the ad's calculated size for the proposal width:

```swift
@available(iOS 16.0, *)
func sizeThatFits(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize,
                  uiViewController: BannerViewController,
                  context: Context) -> CGSize? {
    GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(proposal.width ?? viewWidth).size
}
```

I'm using it with a List and `safeAreaInset`:

```swift
List {
    ...
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
    BannerView()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    struct TabView: View {
    
      @State private var adBannerHeight = 0.0 
     
      var body: some View {
          VStack {
              Text("Foo")
              Spacer()
              BannerView(adBannerHeight: $adBannerHeight)
             .frame(maxHeight: adBannerHeight)
          }
      }
    }
```

Inside the BannerView `struct`, add a Binding for the `adBannerHeight`

```
@Binding var adBannerHeight: Double
```

Update the `Coordinator` class inside `BannerView` - it was enough to change `bannerViewDidReceiveAd` to the following:

```
func bannerViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("DID RECEIVE AD")
    parent.adBannerHeight = parent.bannerView.adSize.size.height
    parent.didReceiveAd = true
}
```

Each time an ad is received the ad height is  written to the binding and the calling view is updated with the state change if necessary.